# Angular 2 Bind only 3 checkboxes in each row dynamically

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, html-table

Am binding checkboxes dynamically but irrespective number of checkboxes, I need to display only 3 checkboxes in each row. How can I achieve this? Not only checkboxes, how can we display only 3 dynamic data out of many in each row in Angular?

Note: The data will be dynamic.

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let aar of appAccessRights">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let item of aar.applicationPermissions">
            <input type="checkbox" id="AppPermissions{{item.id}}" class="k-checkbox" name="AppPermissions{{item.id}}">
            <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="AppPermissions{{item.id}}">{{item.permissions}}</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: When you say that you want only 3 checkboxes per row, do you mean only 3 `li` elements?

Comment: @ConnorsFan means i will get around 20 json data for checkboxes form api...and i need to display that 20 checkboxes in a table but only 3 checkboxes i need to display in each row. So that there will be 7 rows and 3 checkboxes in each row.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I am aware of is to use [Angular's flex-layout library](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). With this, you have multiple options to create rows with row wrapping or grids with a specific width. [The wiki](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) is another good direct link to more info on this.

The `wrap` options is described more [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview).

A pseudo-ish example could be:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of aar.applicationPermissions">
        <div fxFlex="33.3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="AppPermissions{{item.id}}" class="k-checkbox" name="AppPermissions{{item.id}}">
            <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="AppPermissions{{item.id}}">{{item.permissions}}</label>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```